# Quick Flex and Java tutorial

Tags: java, flex4

I need to build an application that works with Java and Flex. I worked with both, but separately, never combined. Can somebody gives me some useful links that help me to get familiar with both?

Thank advance!

Comment: I think that I found what i was looking for: http://subinsugunan.blogspot.com/2009/06/flex-blazeds-java-communication-part-1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi man you should try remoting services to invoke your java classes directly from you flex app
its a simple way to integrate them together.
There are many tools to integrate them such as Blaze DS(open source) or Granite DS(also opensource i think i didnt try it)

I think remote classes is the simplest way to use the power of java and flex

Check out this Links:

http://www.jamesward.com/2010/01/11/flash-builder-4-data-wizards-with-java-spring/

http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/03/video-using-the-flash-builder-4-data-wizards-with-blazeds-4/

http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/alexb/archive/2010/05/25/flash-builder-4-the-easiest-way-to-create-a-combined-flex-java-project.aspx

Greetings...

Answer (score 1):

The following links will be of some help:

http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/tutorial-on-integrating-flex-with-struts-based-application-using-remoting/

http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/building-flex-and-java-based-crud-application-using-flash-builder-4/

Comment: I even do not use struts. So i need something "simpler"